# Order of releasing the semaphores

Tags: operating-systems, mutual-exclusion, critical-section, semaphore

I was studying the dining philosopher problem ([See problem description](https://www.javatpoint.com/os-dining-philosophers-problem)) and its solution using semaphores, and I came across this :

```
**Code for the ith philosopher:**

 while(1)  

  {  

   take_chopstick[i];  
   take_chopstick[ (i+1) % 5] ;  
    
   EATING THE NOODLE  
   
   put_chopstick[i] );  
   put_chopstick[ (i+1) % 5] ;  
   
   THINKING  

  }
```

I had two doubts here:

1. Can the order of putting back the chopsticks be reversed, i.e. the (i+1) th chopstick is put back first, and then the ith chopstick? Why/Why not?
2. In general, when we have two semaphores, do we release that semaphore first, which was locked later? Or are there any guidelines regarding the same?

Comment: I'd not call those *doubts*, but valid questions. Another one: With an even number of philosophers, is there an advantage to having the even numbered ones picking up the left chopstick first, the odd ones the right? Please add your thoughts to your above post.

Comment: @greybeard They would both be picking up the same chopstick, hence it can lead to deadlock. But how is your question relevant to mine?

Comment: Not the extra question as such is relevant to yours: The prompt to add your thoughts is. (I thought it possible that musing about an extra question might bring up ideas more easily put into words. And spark similar for your bullet points.)